# How to create a web app based on Location Hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to make a modern webapp that uses location hash for navigation and ajax requests.  I will be using jQuery, and I assume I need to use a plugin such as http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/ ?

Comment: Whats the question ? how to use the plugin ? whats the best plugin ? this is a Q/A site not an opinion poll !

Comment: The post is to 1) Make sure I know what I'm talking about and 2) To find out the best plugin to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address) on a few projects now, really great plugin!

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address

It handles all of your hash changes, has great functions and callbacks for capturing changes internally and externally (like with the browser forward/back button) and can also record all changes with your Google Analytics so you still have you page view data.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't heard of this plugin before.  Based on github commit history and number of watchers, it looks this plugin is the better way to go.

Comment: I'll have to try it next time :)

Comment: Yeah it really is a great resource. Hope it works well for you :)

Answer (score 1):

That plugin is exactly what I use.  It's great.  All you need to do is listen for hash change events and update your page content accordingly.